# What is the perfect sprite size for new ipads with retina displays

Tags: sprites, image, resolution, scale

The graphic designer is sending me huge sprites 3000px in width drawn by hand. And now the company is hiring a professional painter to paint huge oil paintings for the game for other levels. Nothing digital. I receive PNG.

The game is a clicking game where you find hidden stuff, puzzle. So the slightest details matters. Everything must look so perfect. Primary devices are the ipads with retina displays but the game must be cross platform.

- What is the size I should ask the painter to paint? And the graphic designer to draw?
- What is the best size for a background PNG? And what size is the items? currently I resize to 600 * 400 the background and the items are 100px by whatever height photoshop deems good.

I'm afraid to go smaller than that, even though technically I should be able to. Another programmer working on the game, resized them down so much and they got stretched.

Comment: Depending on the art you usually have high res versions and then scale them down to each platform. Keep in mind that you need to compress your images to target specific compressions or you can suffer performance loss. So look into properly compressing your assets as well.

Comment: As explained in this question "[What sprite size should I use for 2D game?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/140072/what-sprite-size-should-i-use-for-2d-game)" there isn't really any one "perfect" sprite size for every game, just a lot of judgement calls that you the developer will need to make, based on your target visual look and the resolutions you want to support.